# Vue 3 How to add plugin through vue-cli like from UI?

Tags: vue.js, plugins, vuex, vuejs3

With vue UI we can add `vuex` or `vue-router` plugin which will be automatically appended to the main file like bellow

```js
createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

And creates file `/router/index.js` and `/store/index.js` with default template like bellow which is really nice.

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({

  state: {
  },

  mutations: {
  },

  actions: {
  },

  modules: {
  }

})
```

Is there any other alternative way(vue-cli or npm) to add new plugins with facilities described above? npm install just adds the dependencies(as expected).

Comment: Yes, you can start the `vue-ui` by running `vue ui` (when globally installed) or `npx vue ui` (when locally installed), select your project and install your plugins. They'll be setup with default configuration. But for the auto default config, the plugin must be configured for that. Its not magic ;) A lot of plugins aren't configured automatically. For them you have to take a look in the documentation (probably on github) or example projects.

Comment: each plugin has its own config, some are used directly without any config like element ui plus

Answer (score 0):

You can add CLI plugins from the command line, using [`@vue/cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli) commands (i.e., `vue add PLUGIN_NAME`) run from the root directory of your project.

For example, these commands add Vuex and Vue Router to your Vue CLI generated project:

```
vue add vuex
vue add router
```

`vue add` looks for the plugin by prefixing `@vue/cli-plugin-` to the specified name. So the above command automatically installs [`@vue/cli-plugin-vuex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-vuex) and [`@vue/cli-plugin-router`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-router). You can find several other [Vue CLI plugins on `npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=%40vue%2Fcli-plugin) that can be installed the same way.